# Remove item from nested array by indices (recursion)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an array of nested objects. These objects take one of two forms:

```
// type a
{
    value: 'some value'
}
```

or

```
// type b
{
    array: [
        object of type a or b,
        object of type a or b,
        ...
    ]
}
```

So, the base array can be nested infinitely. Given a series of indices (I've been calling it a 'tree'), how can I remove a single item at any depth?

A sample of what I have so far:

```
const baseArray = [
    { value: 'some value' },
    { array: [
            { value: 'some value' },
            { array: [
                    { value: 'some value' },
                    { value: 'some value' },
                ],
            },
            { value: 'some value' },
            { array: [
                    { value: 'some value' },
                    { array: [
                            { value: 'delete me' },
                            { value: 'some value' },
                        ]
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
]

const tree = [1, 3, 1, 0]

function deleteNested(tree, inputArray) {
    const index = tree.shift();
    console.log(inputArray, index);
    const child = inputArray[index].array;
    if (tree.length > 0) {
        console.log(child)
        return deleteNested(tree, child);
    }
    return [
        ...inputArray.slice(0, index),
        ...inputArray.slice(index + 1)
    ]
}
const originalArray = baseArray.slice(0);
console.log(deleteNested(tree, baseArray), originalArray);
```

I want to delete the marked object given it's 'tree' location: `[1, 3, 1, 0]`:

- first, look in the 1 (index of 1, not 0) value of the initial array,
- then the 3 value,
- then look at the 1 value,
- then finally remove the 0 value.

What I have above isn't working, but has gotten me started.

The function needs to be recursive to work at any depth. It should ideally not use `splice()` to avoid modifying the array passed into it -- rather, it should return a new one.

Comment: I guess instead of recursion a while loop would be more appropriate since you already know the number of iterations in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comments if you know the number of iterations in advance you shouldn't use a recursive approach. A while loop is ideal such as;

```js
function delNestedItem(a,dm){
  var i = 0;
  while (i < dm.length-1) a = a[dm[i++]].array;
  a.splice(dm[i],1);
}

var data = [
    { value: 'some value' },
    { array: [
            { value: 'some value' },
            { array: [
                    { value: 'some value' },
                    { value: 'some value' },
                ],
            },
            { value: 'some value' },
            { array: [
                    { value: 'some value' },
                    { array: [
                            { value: 'delete me' },
                            { value: 'some value' },
                        ]
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
          ],

delMark = [1, 3, 1, 0];
delNestedItem(data,delMark);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in 1 reduce:

```js
const baseArray = [{
  value: 'some value'
}, {
  array: [{
    value: 'some value'
  }, {
    array: [{
      value: 'some value'
    }, {
      value: 'some value'
    }, ],
  }, {
    value: 'some value'
  }, {
    array: [{
      value: 'some value'
    }, {
      array: [{
        value: 'delete me'
      }, {
        value: 'some value'
      }, ]
    }, ],
  }, ],
}];

const tree = [1, 3, 1, 0];


var deleted = tree.reduce(function(pos, pathIndex, index, arr) {
  if (index + 1 < arr.length) {
    return pos.array
      ? pos.array[pathIndex]
      : pos[pathIndex];
  } else {
    pos.array = pos.array
            .slice(0, pathIndex)
            .concat(pos.array.slice(pathIndex + 1));
    return pos;
  }

}, baseArray);
            
            console.log(baseArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a new array out of the given array only with the undeleted parts.

```js
function ff(array, tree) {
    function iter(array, level) {
        var r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a, i) {
            if (tree[level] !== i) {
                return r.push(a);
            }
            if (level + 1 !== tree.length && a.array) {
                r.push({ array: iter(a.array, level + 1) });
            }
        });
        return r;
    }
    return iter(array, 0);
}

var baseArray = [{ value: 'some value' }, { array: [{ value: 'some value' }, { array: [{ value: 'some value' }, { value: 'some value' }, ], }, { value: 'some value' }, { array: [{ value: 'some value' }, { array: [{ value: 'delete me' }, { value: 'some value' }, ] }, ], }, ], }],
    tree = [1, 3, 1, 0],
    copy = ff(baseArray, tree);

console.log(copy);
console.log(baseArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```